# Residue of division of $x^n$ by $1-x$?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Is there a name for the residue of dividing $x^n$ by $(x-1)^m$, where $n>m$?

Obviously, it is a polynomial $P$ of degree $m-1$. It is easy to see that the result of the division is $$x^{n-m} + \binom{m}{1} x^{n-m-1} + \binom{m+1}{2} x^{n-m-2} + \dotsc + \binom{n-1}{n-m},$$ and so the coefficient of $x^i$ ($i<m$) in $P$ equals
$$- \sum_{j=0}^{\min(i,m)} (-1)^{m-j} \binom{m}{j} \binom{n-1-(i-j)}{n-m-(i-j)}.$$
Does this ring a bell?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of obtaining the polynomial is to use the binomial theorem as follows:-

$x^n=(1+x-1)^n=1+n(x-1)+\binom{n}{2}(x-1)^2+ ... +\binom{n}{m-1}(x-1)^{m-1}$.

Comment: $+$ a multiple of $(x-1)^{m-1}$. Nice.

Comment: Yes thanks, I should have made it clear it was modulo $(x-1)^m$.